# Babel setup error: "ERROR in ./src/js/index.js"

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

**UPDATE:** I fixed the issue. Look in answers.

**Goal:** Set up Babel.

**Issue:** I run into an error when I use webpack to create a bundle.js file using the command: `npm run dev`.
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CaVR.png) [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Hx2.png)

**./src/js/index.js**

```
import num from "./test";
const x = 45;
console.log(`I imported ${num} from test.js - ${x}`);
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/js/index.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "js/bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist"
    },
    plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "index.html",
        template: "./src/index.html"
    })
    ],
    module: {
    rules: [ 
        {
        test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        use: { 
            loader: "babel-loader"
                }
        }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: You're missing a module: `npm i -D @babel/core`

Comment: I have the package installed already. It shows up in my package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error. Turns out I needed to install new Babel packages.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env
npm install --save @babel/polyfill
```

Replace `entry` in webpack.config.js with:

```
entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/js/index.js"],
```

Replace `presets` in .babelrc with:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing `babel-core`

I think running:

> npm install --save-dev babel-core

Should fix it

Comment: I have the package installed already. It shows up in my package.json file.

Comment: Just saw your other comment about it being in package.json. Try deleting `node_modules`, and then `npm install` again

Comment: Or, to confirm it is indeed installed, open the `node_modules` folder, and see if you can see the `babel-core` folder

Comment: Babel-core is in node_modules.

Comment: what's in the `/.test` file?

Comment: console.log("imported module");
export default 333;

Comment: Purpose of it was to check if the files are connected.

Comment: Did you try deleting `node_modules` and then re-running `npm install`?

Comment: I fixed the issue! Look at the answer I posted if you're interested. Thanks!